# C# Windows Phone How to stop a BackgroundDownloader?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using C# on Windows Phone 8.1 (as Universal App).
I have multiple BackgroundDownloader which can download files at the same time.
I can Pause or Resume files when is downloading or not.

now I have a problem in this application, 
how can I Stop a BackgroundDownload and remove it?
I've used Cancel and Dispose CancellationTokenSource but it's not working and when a user restart the application, old background downloads which user removed, is continue and re-download.

thanks alot

Comment: Have you tried like this: `foreach (var bTask in await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()) bTask.AttachAsync().Cancel();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Cancel` on the `IAsyncOperationWithProgress<DownloadOperation, DownloadOperation>` you get when you call `StartAsync` (or `AttachAsync` if you attach to persisted downloads when the app restarts).